# ParsleyJS - Validate multiple fields

Tags: jquery, parsley.js

I'm trying to validate multiple fields at once, but e.g. `$('select[name="country"], input[name="prefix"]').parsley().validate();` is not working.

To be precise, the `select` seems to be the issue as I can validate `$('input[name="prefix"]').parsley().validate();` but `$('select[name="country"]').parsley().validate();` is not working :(

What could be the reason? Thanks for your input, I'm still learning...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently `parsley` does not work on a set of elements, in that case validation is only applied to first element from the set.

An alternative to work-around your problem would be to loop the set of elements as follows:

```
$('input:first, input:last, select').each(function(index, el){
  $(el).parsley().validate();
});
```

See **[working JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/cpbdmmLn/)**.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I forked (http://jsfiddle.net/gsb8x1dq/) your JSFiddle to get a bit closer to my form reality: 3 select fields. Any idea how I can validate the second select? :first and :last leave my middle select untouched unfortunately...

Comment: I fiddled a bit more and `$(window).load(function() {
  $('select:first, select[name="currency"], input[name="prefix"]').each(function(index, el){
    $(el).parsley().validate()});
});` did the trick. Thanks again!